# Canvas ShadowBlur different in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, canvas

I am trying to render a circle with a blurred shadow in a HTML5 canvas using the shadowBlur option.
But it gives me different results using Chrome and Firefox: 
[image: Left is Chrome, right is Firefox]

My sourcecode is:

```
var blur = 50;
var r = 50;

var r2 = r + blur;

ctx.shadowOffsetX = ctx.shadowOffsetY = r2 * 2;
ctx.shadowBlur = blur;
ctx.shadowColor = 'black';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(-r2, -r2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Or in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eyddLyne/7/

What do I have to change to get the same result in both browsers (The right one from firefox is prefered)?

I tested this with Chrome 48 and Firefox 45.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this that does not involve hardcoding for each browser, as the units of the `shadowBlur` property is browser-dependent.